# database table isn't getting updated but query is getting executed and data in the textbox is being echoed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that consists of a html table which contains data thats being retrieved from the database with the help of a php function. One of the columns in the table is a edit button. On clicking the edit button it navigates to a update form page. The rows in my database are 
para_id=is the parameter number , id= user id , parameter_no = row id, para_date, para_time, reading, type

progpre.php(table page)

```
<?php
         if(!$blood_pressure) { 
            echo '<td><h4>Nothing To Display. Add In Details<h4><td>'; 
                               }                                                       
         else {
           foreach ($blood_pressure as $single) {
            echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>$single[para_date]</td>";
               echo "<td>$single[para_time]</td>";
               echo "<td>$single[reading] $single[type]</td>";
               echo "<td><form action='updatepressure.php' method='GET'><input type='hidden' name='edit' value='$single[parameter_no]'><input type='submit' value='Edit' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='updatepressure.php'></form></td>";
              echo "</tr>";
             }
           }
   ?>
```

updatepressure.php (Update page)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
              $_edit=print_r( $_GET['edit']);

              $para_date = print_r($_POST['para_date']);   
              $para_time = print_r($_POST['para_time']);         
              $reading = print_r($_POST['reading']);
              $type = print_r($_POST['type']);
              //$parameter_no = print_r($_POST['edit']);




               global $conn;
  if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tracking_para` SET `para_date`=?,`para_time`=?,`reading`=?,`type`=? WHERE `parameter_no`=$_edit ")) echo "hi";


             {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $para_date, $para_time, $reading, $type);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}

}
    ?>
```

idk where i'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to insert the output of [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to your database?

If so, what is wrong here is that you have not set the $output parameter for your calls to `print_r()`. This parameter defaults to `false` so it will not return the string you are expecting to insert to your database.

Update your code to look like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
              $_edit=print_r( $_GET['edit'],true);

              $para_date = print_r($_POST['para_date'],true);   
              $para_time = print_r($_POST['para_time'],true);         
              $reading = print_r($_POST['reading'],true);
              $type = print_r($_POST['type'],true);
              //$parameter_no = print_r($_POST['edit'],true);

              ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You use POST

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

but send data with GET

```
echo "<td><form action='updatepressure.php' method='GET'><input type='hidden' name='edit' value='$single[parameter_no]'><input type='submit' value='Edit' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='updatepressure.php'></form></td>";
```

In this way can't work  ..

Try  using POST in all code section